# document.write () should delete all existing html after my page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I red this:

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an
>   HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

So I decided to test this, I wrote this code:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body>
    <p>I'm TEST which should be a deleted?</p>
        <script>
            var drink = "Red bull";
            var lyrics = "";
            var cans = 99;

            while(cans > 0)
            {
                lyrics += cans + " cans of " + drink + " on the wall <br>";   
                cans--;  
            }
            document.write(lyrics);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I added `<p>I'm TEST which should be a deleted?</p>` 
after that I invoked `document.write` between my `script` tag which should delete all existing html including this paragraph?

But output is next:

[image]

But paragraph is still there, shouldn't it be removed by following this sentence:

> If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete
>   all existing HTML.

Comment: The page is rendered if the parser reaches the </html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document isn't yet done loading when the script is running because the script is not at the end of the document (after the `</html>` end tag).

`document.write()` will only erase the existing contents when run after all the markup has been processed, either in a console or in an event handler fired after the fact.

Answer (score 5):

`document.write(lyrics);` is invoked during the loading of the page.

Declare it in a function :

```
<script>  
  function writeData(){
    document.write(lyrics);
  }
</script>
```

and invoke the function at a time where the document was fully loaded
and you should see another behavior.

For example with a button click :

```
<button onclick="writeData()">WriteData</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically answered it yourself

> after an HTML document is fully loaded

If you test it with a timeout, you will see that it will replace the paragraph (note: this is just an example, you should definitely not approach a forced load like this if it's a needed function)

```
        setTimeout(function() {
          while(cans > 0)
          {
              lyrics += cans + " cans of " + drink + " on the wall <br>";   
              cans--;  
          }
          document.write(lyrics);
        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Test it with this code. You will get to know what document.write() actually do. Upon clicking the button the HTML will get hide and you will only see the 11(document.write(5+6)) answer. This is what "The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML." means.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="document.write(5 + 6)">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```